# why does vector.erase remove all my duplicates?

Tags: c++, vector, unique, erase

I'm trying to delete duplicates of numbers in a vector. i use this to do that:

```
vec1.erase(   unique(vec1.begin(),vec1.end())   ,vec1.end());
```

found it with google and it works just fine, my question is WHY?
according to what I've read on cplusplus, **erase** removes from the first parameter to the last.
ex:

```
vec1.erase(vec1.begin(),vec1.begin()+3);  //removes first 3 elements
```

and **unique** returns a pointer to the first duplicate, so in simpler version what I'm writing is:

```
vec1.erase(first duplicate, vec1.end());
```

shouldn't my vector end after the first duplicate?

Comment: cplusplus is not considered a good reference.  Try reading [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique` eliminates unique elements in-place and returns a pointer to the resulting end of the range.  For example,

```
1 2 2 3 3 3
^begin      ^end
```

becomes

```
1 2 3 . . . (garbage)
      ^ resulting end
```

You're thinking of `std::adjacent_find`, which does return an iterator to the first duplicate element.